# Issue when playing DashCast live stream

Tags: apache, screen, mpeg-dash, dashcast

I'm trying to capture desktop and stream it live in an Apache server using DashCast. It captures and plays correctly when I do it on demand, however when I do it live and then play with `MP4Client` it shows only a black screen, not even getting any error message while capturing it. The commands I’m using are:

```
DashCast -vf x11grab -vres 1280x720 -v :0.0 -npts -live -out /public_html/
```

And then I play with:

```
MP4Client http://localhost/vitor/dashcast.mpd
```

Which results in the following output:

```
MP4Client http://localhost/vitor/dashcast/dashcast.mpd
Using config file in /home/vitor directory
System info: 11948 MB RAM - 8 cores
Modules Found : 36 
Loading GPAC Terminal
[Thread MediaManager] Couldn't set priority(2) for thread ID 0x9b55a700
[Thread MediaManager] Couldn't set priority(2) for thread ID 0x9b55a700
Terminal Loaded in 35 ms
Opening URL localhost/vitor/dashcast/dashcast.mpd
[DASH] Slight drift in UTC clock at time 2015-08-05T12:38:45Z: diff AST - now 3563501 ms
Service Connected
```

So what am I doing wrong? The client apparently connects correctly to the server, open the player but then it doesn't show anything on screen. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with GPAC version 0.5.0.

Comment: What is http://localhost/vitor/dashcast.mpd? ---- I get this error: Cannot open service: Requested URL is not valid or cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

```
[DASH] Slight drift in UTC clock at time 2015-08-05T12:38:45Z: diff AST - now 3563501 ms
```

This message indicates that there is a difference ('slight' is a wrong word here given the actual difference !) between the UTC time indicated in the MPD in the availabilityStartTime attribute and the current time that MP4Client uses to compute which segment to fetch. This is only relevant for live because for on demand, all segments are assumed to be available all the time.

MP4Client uses different strategies to determine the 'current' time. The system time on the client may be different from the system time on the server, if they are using different NTP servers for instance. System time is not reliable. So MP4Client tries to get the time from the server. It first tries to use a specific HTTP "Server-UTC" header that the server may set. See for example [this code](https://github.com/gpac/node-gpac-dash/blob/master/gpac-dash.js#L405). If this header is not set, it looks at the HTTP "Date" Header, even if it's not very precise. In your case, your HTTP server probably has a time configuration that does not match the system time. You can tell MP4Client to stop using the server information and to rely on its system time. Since you are using client and server on the same machine, that should work. The documentation of that option is [here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/gpac/gpac/blob/master/doc/configuration.html). For that, use:

```
MP4Client http://localhost/file.mpd -opt DASH:UseServerUTC=no
```

Alternatively, you can try to play the MPD locally without going through the web server.

```
MP4Client file.mpd
```

If that is not working, open an issue on GPAC's GitHub providing as much information as possible, in particular the result of `MP4Box -version`.